# Ruby code to run an executable file in Ubuntu12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04

I have to run  an executable file using ruby.How it is possible?
Am using following code.also how can i check that file is executed or not

```
f = IO.popen("~/local/bin/test")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Ruby's Kernel#system method to run commands. This will return true if the command ran successfully and false otherwise:

```
system('~/local/bin/test')
```

Taken from here: http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby/ There are other options, too. It depends whether you want to run it in the current process, create a sub-process, need to know the execution state etc.